# Detect to android emulator for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

What Android Emulator for Visual Studio used on this screenshot?

[image: emulator screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is no emulator, it is [Vysor](https://www.vysor.io/) an app to mirror the screen to your desktop. Besides mirroring you can also control your phone from the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

It's screen mirroring software to share mobile screens to the desktop. That is no emulator

https://www.vysor.io/
[image]